# How to modify the sorting of cleveref?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, sorting, cleveref

In the backmatter of my document I have the part with plates.
Each page is one plate with several figures in it. The counter for the figures starts on each page/plate, but the number of the figure consists also of the page/plate number (plate.figure).

Everything works except that `cleveref` cannot sort the references properly, because it sorts only by the figure, but not by the whole number (plate.figure).

How can I make `cleveref` to consider the whole number for sorting?

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Taf.}      
\usepackage[sort]{cleveref}
\addto\captionsngerman{%
       \crefformat{figure}{#2Taf. #1#3}
      }
\crefmultiformat{figure}{#2Taf. #1#3}{; #2#1#3}{; #2#1#3}{; #2#1#3}

\begin{document}

How it is:
 \cref{fig:f,fig:b,fig:a,fig:c,fig:d,fig:e}

 How it should be:
 Taf. 1.1; 13.1; 22.1; 1.2; 13.2; 22.2

\counterwithin{figure}{page}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{figure}{0}    

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Figure 1}
\label{fig:a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Figure 2}
\label{fig:b}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{13}%for demonstration
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Figure 3}
\label{fig:c}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Figure 4}
\label{fig:d}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{22}%for demonstration
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Figure 5}
\label{fig:e}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Figure 6}
\label{fig:f}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `cleveref` manual gives no clue about changing the sorting algorithm and looking into `cleveref.sty` will involve a deeper analysis. I suspect that the main cause of this is that the `page` counter is a very unreliable and unfriendly fellow ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: So it would be better to install a new counter instead of using the page-counter?

Comment: Yes, something like a `section` counter or introducing a `\panel` command that does step the panel counter.